# Help reading analog video?

Tags: video, analog, digitisation

I have a microcassette tape with some video on it that I'd like to digitize, but the camera I have that can play microcassette tapes is so old its drivers come on a floppy disk, which I can't read with any of my computers.

However, I can use a firewire cable to transfer the video, but none of my computers have a firewire port, so I bought a firewire-to-usb cable.

I've tried using `WinDV` `VideoDub` and `dvgrab` to capture the tape, however both `WinDV` and `VideoDub` suffer from the problem that Windows has no drivers for the camera, and `dvgrab` can't find the camera in Arch Linux, probably for the same reason.

Is there a way of using the equipment I have to read the video, or will I have to purchase a floppy disk reader to get the drivers?

Answer (score 1):

Even with a floppy drive, you may be SOL -- it's likely the drivers won't work in your current OS. You might have to fire up a virtual machine with an older OS.

If the video is analog, consider a USB video capture device. [Here's](http://www.tigerdirect.com/applications/category/category_slc.asp?CatId=1428) a whole page of them, or search for "USB video capture".

Answer (score 0):

If the camera has a firewire cable then it can send out a DV signal through it, like any other DV camera. so you should be able to capture it, and you won't need specific drivers for it.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_1394#DV

A firewire to USB adaptor isn't going to work though, you'll need a [DV capture card](http://www.ebay.com.au/itm/DV-Video-Capture-Three-1394-Port-Full-Height-PCI-E-Add-On-Cards-/111690081775) for your machine. There are plenty and they're not too expensive — try to find one that comes with free video capture software.

I'm guessing that it's not really a microcassette camera — microcassettes are a subcompact [audio recording format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microcassette) and not something you could possibly record video on. Given the existence of a firewire connection I'd be prepared to bet cash money that it's actually [miniDV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DV#Magnetic_tape).

Comment: Given that there's video on the cassette, you're probably right. I am by no means an expert in this field.